# How is it possible to determine whether the ball will hit the ceiling or not?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, projectile

[image: ?]

There was this question on my exam which I was unable to solve, can anyone help me solving it.

Comment: Welcome to the Physics stack exchange! - you should read the policy regarding homework like questions though.  But really all you need to do is to parametrise the trajectory of the ball and see if the coordinates $(x,6.5)$ lie on it for any $x$.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a simple projectile motion problem.

Resolve the velocity into the horizontal and vertical component, i.e. $15cos\theta$ and $15sin\theta$ respectively.

Now, using equation of motion we get,

$v^2 = u^2 + 2aS,$

$where, v^2 = 0$

The final velocity $v$ is taken as zero so that we can get the maximum height achieved by the ball.

Substituting the respective values,

$0 = (15sin\theta)^2 - 2gH$

$H = \frac{225sin^250^o}{2*10}$

(I've considered acceleration due to gravity to be 10 $ms^{-2}$)

Calculate the value and add 1.5m to it. If it is greater than 8, then the ball will hit the ceiling, else not.

Answer (score -1):

Hint : we could calculate the vertical kinetic energy of the ball and then translate to potential energy and height. Then added to 1.5m gives the maximal height reached.

Comment: "Vertical kinetic energy" is not a thing. You mean the kinetic energy, full stop.

Comment: The "vertical kinetic energy" thing is a little subtle. Energy is a scalar so it doesn't have components which makes @march's comment entirely reasonable. However, Galilean relativity means that the problem can be worked in a frame moving horizontally WRT the original one such that the motion is entirely vertical. In that frame the (a) KE is that result from the vertical component of velocity in the original frame and (b) the work done by gravity is the same as in the original problem. All of which means that you *can* concentrate your efforts on "the energy due to vertical velocity".